# Configure build-in the Jackson MapDeserializer

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I have a project with spring mvc and i wanna invoke method "setIgnorableProperties" from MapDeserializer globally, but I dont know how get this class from ObjectMapper, can you help me? Thx for advice.
 I see it, like that:

```
@Override
public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    mapDeserializer.getContentType();
    converters.forEach(httpMessageConverter -> {
        if (httpMessageConverter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
            MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) httpMessageConverter;
            ObjectMapper mapper = converter.getObjectMapper();
            MapDeserializer mapDes = mapper.(What I have to invoke?) ;
            mapDes.setIgnorableProperties({"@id", "@ref"});
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That property is not meant to be configured directly; you will need to use `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation for `Map`-valued properties.
You can create convenience annotation, if you want, by:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) // IMPORTANT
@JacksonAnnotationsInside
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "@id", "@ref" })
public @interface MapIgnorals
```

and then use like:

```
public class Stuff {
   @MapIgnorals public Map<String,Object> values;
}
```

Comment: Thank you StaxMan, it works, but I've found, that checking for ignorable are processing after trying parse the property and I get exception, cause, for example, if I have generic map with <Long, Long> and jackson do Long.parseLong for the property.

Comment: @DmitryKrasaev not sure I understand what you are saying here -- typing for `Map` is independent of ignorals

Comment: Sorry @StaxMan, I've meant that  parsing a value doing before checking for ignorance, you can see source of MapDeserializer. But I need checking before.